# How to correctly escape special characters in python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Im trying to run this bash command using python subprocess

```
find /Users/johndoe/sandbox -iname "*.py" | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF}'
```

output:-

```
helld.xl.py
parse_maillog.py
replace_pattern.py
split_text_match.py
ssh_bad_login.py
```

Here is what i have done in python2.7 way, but it gives the output where awk command filter is not working

```
>>> p1=subprocess.Popen(["find","/Users/johndoe/sandbox","-iname","*.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

>>> p2=subprocess.Popen(['awk','-F"/"','" {print $NF} "'],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

>>>p2.communicate()
('/Users/johndoe/sandbox/argparse.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/custom_logic_substitute.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/finditer_html_parse.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/finditer_simple.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/group_regex.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/helo.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/newdir/helld.xl.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/parse_maillog.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/replace_pattern.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/split_text_match.py\n/Users/johndoe/sandbox/ssh_bad_login.py\n', None)
```

I could also get output by using p1 alone here like below,but i cant get the awk working here

```
list1=[]
result=p1.communicate()[0].split("\n")
for item in res:
    a=item.rstrip('/').split('/')
    list1.append(a[-1])
print list1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly passing in shell quoting (and *extra* shell quoting which isn't even required by the shell!) when you're not invoking a shell.  Don't do that.

```
p2=subprocess.Popen(['awk', '-F/', '{print $NF}'], stdin=...
```

When you have `shell=True` you need extra quotes around some arguments to protect them from the shell, but there is no shell here, so putting them in is incorrect, and will cause parse errors by Awk.

However, you should almost never need to call Awk from Python, especially for trivial tasks which Python can easily do natively:

```py
list1 = [line.split('/')[-1]
            for line in subprocess.check_output(
                ["find", "/Users/johndoe/sandbox",
                 "-iname", "*.py"]).splitlines()]
```

In this particular case, note also that GNU `find` already has a facility to produce this result directly:

```py
list1 = subprocess.check_output(
    ["find", "/Users/johndoe/sandbox",
     "-iname", "*.py", "-printf", "%f\\n"]).splitlines()
```

Comment: You amazingly managed to remove the quotes in the `find` command line correctly, so it's not clear why you made this error.

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `p2.communicate()[0].split("\n")`.

It will output a list of lines.

Comment: i could use it but i really want to know how i use `awk` here which involves special chars like `" , { , }, ' , /` etc

Comment: `/` is not any more "special" than `.` or `a`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any reservation using **shell=True** , then this should be pretty simple solution

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess
command='''
find /Users/johndoe/sandbox -iname "*.py" | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF}'
'''
process=Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result=process.communicate()
print result
```